# appcfg.py shows You must be logged in as an administrator

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I try to upload a sample csv data to my GAE app through `appcfg.py`, it shows the below 401 error.

```
2015-11-04 10:44:41,820 INFO client.py:571 Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 2/2) 
2015-11-04 10:44:41,821 INFO client.py:797 Refreshing access_token 

Error 401: --- begin server output ---
You must be logged in as an administrator to access this.
--- end server output ---
```

Here is the command I tried,

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=dev~app --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=data/sample.csv
```

Comment: I assume this may be a related issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33682625/1256219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we do it in order to use custom authentication.

Custom handler in **app.yaml**

```
- url: /remoteapi.*
  script: remote_api.app
```

Custom wsgi app in **remote_api.py** to override `CheckIsAdmin`

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import handler
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import re

MY_SECRET_KEY = 'MAKE UP PASSWORD HERE'  # make one up, use the same one in the shell command
cookie_re = re.compile('^"?([^:]+):.*"?$')


class ApiCallHandler(handler.ApiCallHandler):
    def CheckIsAdmin(self):
        """Determine if admin access should be granted based on the
           auth cookie passed with the request."""
        login_cookie = self.request.cookies.get('dev_appserver_login', '')
        match = cookie_re.search(login_cookie)
        if (match and match.group(1) == MY_SECRET_KEY
            and 'X-appcfg-api-version' in self.request.headers):
            return True
        else:
            self.redirect('/_ah/login')
            return False


app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('.*', ApiCallHandler)])
```

From here we script the uploading of data that was exported from our live app. Use the same password that you made up in the python script above.

```
echo "MAKE UP PASSWORD HERE" | appcfg.py upload_data --email=some@example.org --passin --url=http://localhost:8080/remoteapi --num_threads=4 --kind=WebHook --filename=webhook.data --db_filename=bulkloader-progress-webhook.sql3
```

`WebHook` and `webhook.data` are specific to the `Kind` that we exported from production.

Comment: Make up a password but use it in both places, the shell command and the python secret key.

Comment: I'll offer the bounty now. And I'll ping you once I get into my office :-p)

Comment: asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738222/gae-self-request-cookies-return-an-empty-dict

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `appcfg.py upload_data` command with the development server [edit: as is; see Josh J's answer]. It only works with the `remote_api` endpoint running on App Engine and authenticated with OAuth2.

An easy way to load data into the dev server's datastore is to create an endpoint that reads a CSV file and creates the appropriate datastore entities, then hit it with the browser. (Be sure to remove the endpoint before deploying the app, or restrict access to the URL with `login: admin`.)

Comment: You can use it with the local development server. I do it at work except that we pass the `--email` flag for custom authentication.

Comment: Nice! Edited my answer. Haven't tested, but your answer looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, where `appcfg.py` was not giving me any credentials dialog, so I could not authenticate. I downgraded from GAELauncher 1.27 to 1.26, and the authentication started working again.

Temporary solution: go to https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured/ to get version 1.9.26

Submitted bug report: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=340

Comment: 1.9.26...good call. It actually works without any workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an oauth token for a google account that is not an admin of that project. Try passing the `--no_cookies` flag so that it prompts for authentication again.

Comment: Currently I'm doing this on development side, so I think no need for oauth.

Comment: I asks me to login into my google account and copy pasted the verification code on the terminal. Still it shows `You must be logged in as an administrator to access this.`. Does it requires the owner's gmail id?

Comment: When I run `upload_data` locally I am not prompted for an account. Do you have a handler defined for the remote api URL in your app.yaml that requires an admin?

Comment: there isn't a seperate handler defined for remote api url.. My `app.yaml` file looks like http://pastebin.com/X99EAq19

Comment: Can you boil it down to a minimal application that exhibits the same problem and put it on github or bitbucket?

Comment: @AvinashRaj there is a bug on their tracker from Oct around access tokens. Check [it out](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445) and [this one](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12435) too.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver  is this of use?  from the docs :

Create an environment variable DATASTORE_HOST and set it to the host and port on which the local developmen ... continued

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this has something to do with it? From the docs

> > Connecting your app to the local development server
>
> To use the local development server for your app running locally, you
>   need to do the following:
>
> Set environment variables. Add or modify your app's Datastore
>   connection code. Setting environment variables
>
> Create an environment variable DATASTORE_HOST and set it to the host
>   and port on which the local development server is listening. The
>   default host and port is http://localhost:8080. (Note: If you use the
>   port and/or host command line arguments to change these defaults, be
>   sure to adjust DATASTORE_HOST accordingly.) The following bash shell
>   example shows how to set this variable:
>
> export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8080 Create an environment
>   variable named DATASTORE_DATASET and set it to your dataset ID, as
>   shown in the following bash shell example:
>
> export DATASTORE_DATASET= Note: Both the Python and Java
>   client libraries look for the environment variables DATASTORE_HOST and
>   DATASTORE_DATASET.

Link to Docs

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver