# GAE self.request.cookies return an empty dict

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to override `CheckIsAdmin` method present in `ApiCallHandler` class. So I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33652077/3297613) answer. But I always get empty dict on printing `self.request.cookies`.

At some point I get the values on printing `self.request.cookies` but not it won't. I have checked that my server is running and I'm already looged in.

`remote_api.py` looks like

```
import re
import models
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import handler
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

MY_SECRET_KEY = 'foo@bar.com'  # make one up, use the same one in the shell command


class ApiCallHandler(handler.ApiCallHandler):

    def CheckIsAdmin(self):
        '''
        Determine if admin access should be granted based on the
        auth cookie passed with the request.
        '''

        '''
        print 'App id ' + models.APPLICATION_ID
        print 'on checkIsAdmin'
        print 'request.cookies ' + str(self.request.cookies)
        login_cookie = self.request.cookies.get('dev_appserver_login', '')
        match = login_cookie.split(':')
        print 'headers '+ str(self.request.headers)
        if match and match[0] == MY_SECRET_KEY \
                and 'X-Appcfg-Api-Version' in self.request.headers:
            print 'Going to return true'
            return True

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('.*', ApiCallHandler)])
```

part of `app.yaml` looks like

```
- url: /remoteapi.*
    script: api.remote_api.app
```

This is correct where my `.py` file exists inside `api` folder..

When I'have tried this command,

```
echo "foo@bar.com" | appcfg.py upload_data --email=some@example.org --passin --url=http://localhost:8080/remoteapi --num_threads=4  --db_filename=bulkloader.csv
```

it shows invalid parameter `--passin` and it works perfectly if I placed `return True` at the start of `CheckIsAdmin` method. But it lacks security..

Comment: You know the drill, distill it down to a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know why your cookies are empty because you did not post an example that I can use to recreate your problem. I assume you have something wrong somewhere, but I can only guess without code to look at.

Comment: my friend told me that, we get the values for cookies only when the browser is opened. Did i need to browse `localhost:8080/remoteapi` link?

Comment: Sending a login username and password via `appcfg.py upload_data` should be enough to generate a cookie.

Comment: ya, it shows unrecognized parameter `--passin`

Comment: Let's stop this back and forth. Edit your post to show a [mcve] and I'll try to help. This isn't a realtime troubleshooting forum.

Comment: @JoshJ check my update....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they removed `--passin` and now exclusively rely on oauth.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.9.24_-_July_20,_2015

`--passin` was the flag that caused cookies to get set. It looks like you will need to downgrade to an sdk version below 1.9.24 or change the command to use oauth and remove the custom `ApiCallHandler` code.

Comment: added bounty for this question. Is there no way without downgrading?

Comment: I haven't reviewed the tool lately so I don't know how to get around it. I'm sure you could create a service account and use it's oauth token to do the same.