# Google App Engine - Can't download localhost datastore for uploading to production server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, appcfg

I have a set of data that I would like to use for production but I can't seem to get appcfg.py to download the localhost datastore. I have localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api on in app.yaml then, in the SDK shell, i ran

```
appcfg.py download_data --filename=local.db --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api -A [MYAPPID]
```

I get this error message:

> You must be logged in as an administrator to access this.

I can't find a way to authenticate my google account as the admin. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general issue of remote_api admin authentication to the local development server, you may want to star it: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445. Several workaround suggestions in there (YMMV according to other posts)

[The most recent one](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445#c23) (2 days old) looks promising:

> Workaround for `appcfg.py upload_data` to local dev server,
>   "Refreshing due to a 401" issue. Tested using Java dev server 1.9.42:
>
> 1. Log into the local dev server Development Console in a browser.
> 2. Open your browser's dev tools and pull the value for the `dev_appserver_login` cookie.
> 3. Edit `lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py` in the app.
> 4. Find "def new_request" function. Before line `self.apply(headers)` in this function, add:
>
>    ```
>    headers['Cookie'] = 'dev_appserver_login=your-cookie-value-here';
>    ```
> 5. Run the `upload_data` command.

There's also this recipe, successful at the time, but it *might* be a bit old now: 
[appcfg.py shows You must be logged in as an administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514229/appcfg-py-shows-you-must-be-logged-in-as-an-administrator)