# appcfg.py upload_data won't ask for authentication locally

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

In the local development environment, the upload_data command will not launch a browser for OAuth. Why is that?!?

The code works perfectly fine on App Engine but not the local development environment. Is there a trick to use the remote API for the dev environment.

Here's how I use the command...

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=./stops.txt --kind=StopLocationLoader --url=http://localhost:8082/_ah/remote_api
10:39 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20161017.223916
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
You must be logged in as an administrator to access this.
--- end server output ---
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445

It links to a workaround posted for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34674434/198996):

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth print-access-token
appcfg.py upload_data --oauth2_access_token=<oauth2_access_token> --config_file bulkloader.yaml --url=http://<yourproject>.appspot.com/remote_api --filename places.csv --kind=Place --email=<you@gmail.com>
```

Comment: your example uses the appspot.com domain. intentional? i don't have problems using the bulk loader on app engine. only on the local development environment.

Comment: i've tried using your solution and pointing at localhost and the error is different. now i get a 401 with the error, "error" : "invalid_grant"

Comment: You're right, I mixed that up! However, the link to the issue is indeed correct.  It features [several](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445#c20) [workarounds](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445#c21) for the devserver if you're using Python and even [one for Java](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12445#c23). Tell me if that helps, in that case I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: i've updated the answer but i still can't get that solution to work unfortunately.